# Access elements of Python tuple in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I want to run and access the output of a Python function in Matlab. Please find below function. The python function returns a Python tuple as output in Matlab. Can I access elements of tuple in Matlab? I do not want to export output as .mat file and import it in Matlab, which will be computationally expensive for my work. Thanks

Python code:
python_file name: test_file

```
import numpy as np
def test (x1, x2, x3, x4):
    y = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
    z = y**2   
    return {"y_value":y,"z_value": z}
```

Calling python function in Matlab:

```
f = py.test_file.test(2.2,3.9,4.2,5.1)
```

Output received in Matlab as of 1 by 1 tuple.

```
f = 

  Python tuple with no properties.

    (15.4, 237.16000000000003)
```

Comment: The documentation is quite clear: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pythontuplevariables.html It was the top hit when I googled for “matlab python tuple”.

Answer (score 0):

After you got

```
f = 

  Python tuple with no properties.

    (15.4, 237.16000000000003)
```

Use

```
cellf=cell(f);
```

to [convert it to matlab cells.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pythontuplevariables.html#responsive_offcanvas) Optionally, you may index into the tuple first:

```
cellf12=cell(f(1:2));
```